# Show that the statements $C \subseteq A \cup B$ and $C \setminus A \subseteq B$ are equivalent.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"Show that the statements $C \subseteq (A \cup B)$ and $C \setminus (A \subseteq B)$ are equivalent by writing each in logical symbols and then showing that the resulting formulas are equivalent."

I can't seem to figure this one out at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that the second statement should read $(C \setminus A) \subseteq B$

Comment: **Hint:** The union $(A\cup B)$ consists of three disjoint parts: $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$ and $B\setminus A$. Some of them may be empty. The set $C$ can be dissected accordingly. Can you continue from here...?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Fred in the comments, the second expression shouldn’t be $C \setminus (A \subseteq B)$ but $(C \setminus A) \subseteq B.$ Here’s why.

Applying the definitions of each set operation, we get the following logic expressions.

$$C \subseteq (A \cup B) \iff (\forall x):[x \in C \to (x \in A \vee x \in B)].$$

$$C \setminus (A \subseteq B) \iff (\forall x):[x \in C \wedge \neg (x \in A \to x \in B)].$$

Let’s see why the second is not equivalent to the first.

1. $C \subseteq (A \cup B) \iff (\forall x):[x \in C \to (x \in A \vee x \in B)] \iff$
   $ \iff (\forall x):[x \notin C \vee x \in A \vee x \in B].$
2. $(\forall x):[x \in C \wedge \neg (x \in A \to x \in B)]$ $\iff (\forall x):[x \in C \wedge \neg (x \notin A \vee x \in B)]$
   $ \iff (\forall x):[x \in C \wedge x \in A \wedge x \notin B].$

Suppose that $x \in B.$ Then, for this element, $1.$ would be true and $2.$ would be false, so they are not equivalent.

Although, writing the second expression as $(C \setminus A) \subseteq B$ we get an equivalence.

$$(C \setminus A) \subseteq B \iff (\forall x):[x \in C \setminus A \to x \in B] \iff (\forall x):[x \notin C \setminus A \vee x \in B] \iff (\forall x):[(x \notin C \vee x \in A) \vee x \in B] \iff (\forall x):[(x \notin C) \vee (x \in A \vee x \in B)].$$

Using the **Material Implication,** we see that the last expression is equivalent to

$$(\forall x):[x \in C \to (x \in A \vee x \in B)].$$

Which is equivalent to the logic form of the first expression, therefore $C \subseteq (A \cup B)$ and $(C \setminus A) \subseteq B$ are equivalent.